# Need Bluetooth dongle that works with 20.04

Tags: bluetooth

I need a bluetooth dongle for my laptop.  I tried an EVEO 5.0, Ubuntu recognizes that I plug it in, and on the setup screen I can move the button to "On", but bluetooth never turns on.  I researched here, saw many answers, none of them fixed the problem.

So rather than randomly buy another and hope for the best, who can recommend one that is known to work with 20.04 ?  I just need it for headphones.

thanks

Comment: if you don't need Bluetooth 5.0 then I am using this one (https://www.amazon.com/dp/B009ZIILLI//ref=as_li_ss_tl?ie=UTF8&linkCode=ll1&tag=techlounge0f-20&linkId=abe31eda917ef727bf134cc79f681d70) if you need 5.0 this one says it's linux compatible (https://www.amazon.com/Wireless-Bluetoth-Transmitter-Bluetooth-Headphones/dp/B08BFBJQ7C/ref=sr_1_6?dchild=1&keywords=USB+Bluetooth+dongle+linux&qid=1601495312&sr=8-6)

Comment: Hardware recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: The dongle woks fine.  Thank you for the tip. wraith3690 001

Raspberries Pilot6